# How to migrate elasticsearch indices to data streams

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I was asked to migrate to data streams in elasticsearch. I am a newbie in elasticsearch, and still learning about it. Only useful article I could find: https://spinscale.de/posts/2021-07-07-elasticsearch-data-streams-explained.html#data-streams-in-kibana

Since we are using elasticsearch under basic license, I got error when I was following along with tutorial and creating a ILM policy.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "policy [csc-stream-policy] defines the [searchable_snapshot] action but the current license is non-compliant for [searchable-snapshots]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "policy [csc-stream-policy] defines the [searchable_snapshot] action but the current license is non-compliant for [searchable-snapshots]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Can anyone give me an idea what else I could do to active data streams in elasticsearch? I can confirm that searchable snapshots are not supported in free license. Is there another way around it?

Thanks in advance!